# Django 1.3.1 cannot create sqlite database

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble creating a default sqlite3 database and i'm not sure why:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

This is the error i'm receiving when i try and syncdb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\eclipseProjects\mysite\mysite\manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Django doesn't seem to be using that settings file - the traceback says you haven't set ENGINE, and it's trying to use 'dummy'. So it's ignoring that setting for some reason, which means it must be looking in a different file. Can you show your project layout?

Comment: i'm following the tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: is your `settings.py` definitely getting imported? (e.g. try adding a `print` statement to check it's getting loaded

Comment: OH... i think ti setting file is pointing to the subdirectory settings file instead of the one i was thinking of. How do i change which settings file the project points to?

Comment: You're using a tutorial for the not-yet-release Django 1.5, while you're using the old Django 1.3. The project structure changed in 1.4. You should use the tutorial appropriate to your version.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation more carefully. The NAME should and must be an absolute path. Taken the documentation section 2.3.1

> NAME – The name of your database. If you’re using SQLite, the database
>   will be a file on your computer; in that case, NAME should be the full
>   absolute path, including filename, of that file. If the file doesn’t
>   exist, it will automatically be created when you synchronize the
>   database for the first time (see below).
>
> When specifying the path, always use forward slashes, even on Windows
>   (e.g. C:/homes/user/mysite/sqlite3.db).